# How to get list of all API's and its meta data from Anypoint Cloud

Tags: mule, metadata

we have a need to pull the details of all the API's deployed in anypoint cloud, along with their meta data. Is there a way to pull this info dynamically so that we can schedule it like a job for a daily/weekly basis and load into some kind of DB

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Mulesoft has an Anypoint Runtime Manager (ARM) API that you could make use of. There is some documentation available here: https://docs.mulesoft.com/runtime-manager/runtime-manager-api#applications-runtime-manager-api. In addition, you can take a look at the API Portal which has more in-depth information about all of the endpoints available in the API. Right of the bat, the `/applications:GET` method seems like something you might be able to leverage for your need.
https://anypoint.mulesoft.com/apiplatform/anypoint-platform/#/portals/organizations/ae639f94-da46-42bc-9d51-180ec25cf994/apis/38784/versions/5567732/pages/182845.
Hope that helps!